# Restart a MS Server 2008, without it installing updates?

Tags: windows-server-2008

How do I prevent my Microsoft Server 2008 and SBS 2008 from installing updates when I restart them, occasionally I need to quickly restart them for some software install to take place, but I dont want to have to wait hours for updates to be installed.

**Update** We schedule reboots for server updates, but sometimes I need it to simply reboot, nothing more.

Comment: A quick restart on SBS 2008? Our SBS 2008 server takes about 25 minutes to reboot, updates or no updates, on a dual-quad-core with 8gb of ram and 15k SAS drives!

Comment: I agree, but I can't have the server installing updates for 2 hours, like it did today. It normally takes about 15-20 for it to reboot when not installing upates

Comment: 15-20 min? That's an exceptionally long time! We have a few dozen Dells from 2650s-R900s and some IBM x3650s and nothing takes more than 5-10 min.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the shutdown command:

```
shutdown /r /t 0
```

Answer (score 5):

Totally not answering your question, but just giving some good advice. Stop all Exchange services before shutting down or rebooting...You'll be shocked how much it speeds things up (Take your normal 15 minute reboot down to 5 minutes)